# interpretation software

Tags: software

Does anyone know a software that is able to interpret a report. I need help for regularly marking 90 paper, each about 2000 words. This is ver time consuming. I was wondering if anyone is aware an `AI type software package were it can spot key words.
Many thanks
Siavosh

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think you should not be looking for this. The answers here already tell you that.

Answer (score 7):

Marking is one of the responsibilities that academics never enjoy, because it is time consuming and not very exciting. However, it is your job to do it, and you need to do in properly. Consult your University / college policy on marking and check if it allows the use of such software. It is very likely that as a marker you are expected to read all the reports carefully and mark them based on their content, not just a few keywords.

Answer (score 3):

You're barking up the wrong tree.  There is no software substitute for grading papers by hand. What you need to do is create a rubric, assigning points or penalties to each aspect of the assignment you consider important, so that grading becomes simply a matter of checking off the items that apply, then adding up the result.